# How can I define Avro Schema to catch keys which may come or may not?

Tags: schema, apache-nifi, avro

I'm trying to automatize a task in NiFi, where I have n possible records.

```
{
 "id":"foo",
 "date":"2020-06-24",
 "key_1":
    {
     "bar":"value1"
    }
}
```

Other example:

```
{
 "id":"foo",
 "date":"2020-06-24",
 "key_2":
    {
     "bar":"value2"
    }
}
```

And so on. What I'm pretending to do is use MergeRecord to mix these values by id and date like that:

```
[
    {
     "id":"foo",
     "date":"2020-06-24",
     "key_1":
        {
         "bar":"value1"
        }
    },
    {
     "id":"foo",
     "date":"2020-06-24",
     "key_2":
        {
         "bar":"value2"
        }
    }, 
    ...
]
```

But this is what I have:

```
[
    {
     "id":"foo",
     "date":"2020-06-24",
     "key_1":
        {
         "bar":"value1"
        },
     "key_2":null,
     "key_3":null,...
    },
    {
     "id":"foo",
     "date":"2020-06-24",
     "key_1":null,
     "key_2":
        {
         "bar":"value2"
        }
    },
    "key_3":null,
    ...
]
```

This is my avro schema:

```
{"name":"foo",
 "type":"record",
 "fields":[
    {"name":"id","type":"string"},
    {"name":"date","type":"string"},
    {"name":"key_1",
     "type":["null",{
        "name":"key_1", "type":"record",
        "fields":[
            {"name":"bar","type":"double"}
        ]
     }]},
    {"name":"key_2",
     "type":["null",{
        "name":"key_2", "type":"record",
        "fields":[
            {"name":"bar","type":"double"}
        ]
     }]},
    {"name":"key_3",
     "type":["null",{
        "name":"key_3", "type":"record",
        "fields":[
            {"name":"bar","type":"double"}
        ]
     }]},
     ...
   ],
}
```

I don't know even if there is any way to say NiFi some keys may come or may not. Defining it as type null is my best shot

Answer (score 0):

Nullable fields will be your best bet. It's really Avro that's doing most of the heavy lifting here. Having a sparse record is fine.